# Adding extra information to event registration

Tags: civievent, custom-fields

We organise a walk with a lunch afterwards. Who registers online for the event must be able to indicate how many people will participate for the walk (number of adults and number of kids up to 12 year) and for the lunch (idem).

I do not see the possibility to add those fields to the online registration form. When i define custom fields for the event, they cannot be added to the registration form. When i add a "walk and lunch profile" to be used for these events, the first to know is the existing field of the person (such as last name...).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to make the Custom fields on the Participant record (not on the Event). Then you'll be able to add them into a Profile and add that Profile to the Online Registration section for your Event.

Answer (score 3):

You could have the online registration allow to register multiple participants.  You can have a different profile for the initial participant and a separate profile for the additional participants depending on the information you need for each participant.[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are just needing 'numbers' then you should be able to do this by using a 'number' based field in a Price Set.